# How to connect an android device to a VPN?

Tags: vpn

I have Xperia mini running ICS 4.0.3. I want to connect to a VPN for which I have server address(host) , group name, group passwrod(pre-shared key). but I still couldn't connect to it via my Xperia mini where as the VPN is able to connect in desktop. I have tried in IPsec PSK.

Comment: There is more than one type of VPN (IPsec and SSLVPN are two of the major protocols) and the way some VPN vendors use VPN makes it very hard to connect to them using anything other than their own client. Do you know what VPN brand and protocol it is that you're trying to connect to?

Comment: I am using cisco VPN client and IPsec/UDP protocol to connect to the VPN in my System.

Answer (score 2):

If your company is licensed for it, Cisco's [AnyConnect ICS+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.avf) should work for you. Alternatively, ICS **should** support the correct configuration out of the box, but not all vendors have implemented this properly.

If you can't get it to work correctly using ICS's IPSEC support, you can try [VPNC Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.mjm4456.vpncwidget), but it requires root, and if your phone doesn't have the TUN module built-in, it won't work.